# 7-Segment Decoder outputs/LED display

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, decoder

What would be the difference in using a 7-segment decoder with active-high outputs vs active-low outputs, to driver an LED display?

Answer (score 4):

Some 7 segment displays are common anode, which require a decoder with an active-low output.  Others are common cathode, which require an active-high output.  Choose the decoder appropriate to the display that you want to use.

Comment: @stevesy It seems common-anode displays are more common, as the decoder circuitry in bipolar 74xx series devices drew more power when driving common-cathode displays.  Whether this is also the case with CMOS decoder ICs like the 74HC/HCT series, I am not certain.